# How to hide system player AVPlayerViewController status bar?

Tags: ios, avplayerviewcontroller

I have been in the status bar system were added to the info.plist Status bar is initially hidden-YES and View controller-based status bar appearance- NO to hide the entire project, but the status bar system of AVPlayerViewController player can't hide, how should I do? Hope to get help

Comment: what did you tried? some code would be helpful to understand properly.

Comment: You cannot hide status bar in full screen avplayer mode. When player control goes from screen than status bar will hide automatically.